# Cohorts based on first day of usage

Tags: r, dplyr, transform

I want to build cohorts based on the month of the first observation of a user in my app dataset. Let's say, January 2018 was the first month of my observation period.

I've tried something like this (...not working):

```
da_app = group_by(da, userid) %>%
  mutate(cohort= min(day))
```

Example data:

```
da_app <- data.frame(userid = c(1,1,2,2), day = c("2019-02-20","2019-02-21","2018-03-11","2018-03-12"))
```

```
da_app
  userid        day
1      1 2019-02-20
2      1 2019-02-21
3      2 2018-03-11
4      2 2018-03-12
```

I would like to have this:

```
da_app2
  userid        day cohort
1      1 2019-02-20     14
2      1 2019-02-21     14
3      2 2018-03-11      3
4      2 2018-03-12      3
```

Comment: What's the logic behind `14, 3` as cohort names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `lubridate`, you can do:

```
df %>%
 mutate(cohort = interval(ymd("2018-01-01"), ymd(day)) %/% months(1) + 1)

  userid        day cohort
1      1 2019-02-20     14
2      1 2019-02-21     14
3      2 2018-03-11      3
4      2 2018-03-12      3
```

Answer (score 1):

Just convert `substr` to `factor` with cohort labels w/o extra `library`s. You'll probably need cohort factors anyway.

```
da_app$cohort <- factor(substr(da_app$day, 6, 7), labels=c(14, 3))
da_app
#   userid        day cohort
# 1      1 2019-02-20     14
# 2      1 2019-02-21     14
# 3      2 2018-03-11      3
# 4      2 2018-03-12      3
```

***Data***

```
da_app <- structure(list(userid = c(1, 1, 2, 2), day = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("2018-03-11", "2018-03-12", "2019-02-20", 
"2019-02-21"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```